# Installing MySQL Workbench ⇒ Error

Tags: apt, software-center, mysql

I have installed *MySQL Workbench* in the past using MySQL APT.

My software repositories lists have recently been updated and since then my *MySQL Workbench* disappeared. It is still on the disk but it is not launching.

I tried to go to *Software Center* and try to install it and I receive:

```
mysql-workbench: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but 1:2.24.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7) but 1:8.31-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
                 Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 6.0.8+dfsg-2) but 6.0.8+dfsg-2 is to be installed
```

If I try to install from APT using

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

I get

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: mysql-client
                   Recommends: mysql-utilities but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then if I try to install `mysql-client` dependency, I get a similar error saying that it needs `mysql-community-client`.

If I try to install this community client, I will receive another error saying that it needs `libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed`.

If I try to install this one, it says that I already have this version.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because the `mysql-community-client` package you are trying to download and install requires `libstdc++6 >=4.9`. The latest version of `libstdc++6` available on the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS repositories is `4.8.2-19ubuntu1`, which is older than `4.9`.

I'm assuming that you're running Ubuntu 14.04, because the `libstdc++6` package on your computer is stuck at `4.8.2-19ubuntu1`. The MySQL APT repository currently has packages for three versions of Ubuntu: 12.04, 14.04 and 14.10. `mysql-community-client` for 12.04 and 14.04 both require only `libstdc++6 >=4.6`, while 14.10 requires version `libstdc++6 >=4.9`.

Please check that you've installed [the correct `mysql-apt-config` package](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) for your Ubuntu version.

Comment: This was the problem. I installed the wrong version of APT. I installed APT for 14.10 instead of 14.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You should:

```
sudo apt-get install -f mysql-workbench
```

---

I use in such cases *[aptitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_(software))*

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and then:

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-workbench
```

Suggestions are made that can help solve your problem.

Comment: Forcing MySQL Workbench installation did not solve my problem. Instead, I installed aptitude and probably this would've solved the problem somehow. I didn't go further with this because I already applied @zhongfu's answer.

Comment: @tzortzik, I think that you have chosen the correct answer. My answer is a bit too general.

Comment: @zhongfu Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)